# Incorporate Error-Checking Formula When Copying Excel Vba

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have the following code for copying cells:

```
Set Feeder = Sheets("Projects").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

With Sheets("Database")
    Set Storage = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-Masterrow + 1)
   Storage.Value2 = "=" & "Projects!" & Feeder.Address

End With
```

Is there a way to incorporate the formula `=IFERROR(B2,0)` so that my copy location contains `=IFERROR(Projects!B2,0)` as opposed to `=Projects!B2`?
I want erroneous cells to return a 0 as opposed to an error code so I can just run my delete rows code easily.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was straightforward after realizing I had already constructed a formula before.
Code from before:

```
Storage.Value2 = "=" & "Projects!" & Feeder.Address
```

Code after:

```
Storage.Value2 = "=" & "IFERROR(" & "Projects!" & Feeder.Address & ",0)"
```

Sometimes it really is simple!